# How can I send the value from a dropdown while using reactive forms

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-reactive-forms

I am using a dropdown in a reactive form, I am fetching all the value from the DB in the DD list now I want to send the id value when user clicks on any option of the dropdown. Now when I am trying to get the value using FormControlName *"No value accessor for form control with name"* because I am not using it inside an input field

Here's the DD template

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button (click) = "dd()" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Select Doctor
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li *ngFor="let d of doctor" formControlName="doctorId" value={{d.id}}><a class="dropdown-item"  >{{d.name}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the component.ts

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.patientForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      illness: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      doctorId: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    })
  }
```

Is there any way that I can send the value to the component from the template without using extra components. I wanna get the doctor id in the doctorId instance that's why I was using FormControllName

**Update:**
I tried by calling a click event and passed the id from there and then in the component.ts I assigned it's value in the doctorId and it is working but there is a catch, as I was using Validators so I wanted the submit button to stay disabled until an user completely filled up the form along with the doctors from the DD and now as I am not taking the value from the form itself that validation isn't working because I had to remove all the validations from the FormControll which is not what I want. How am I supposed to make it happen

here's that updated portion

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li *ngFor="let d of doctor"><a href = "javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-item" (click) = "fix(d.id)" >{{d.name}}</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Here's the fix() method in the component.ts file

```
  fix(id: number) {
    this.patientForm.value.doctorId = id;
    // console.log(this.doctor);
  }
```

Comment: Can't you use a select instead of a list for drop down? You can link the control to the select. Or is there any specific requirement?

Comment: It’s all a bit hacky, but you could put a (click) on the li with a function that receives the value and manually puts it on the formControl with .setValue?

Comment: a FormControl is used always inside a "input" (or select) you can get the value using e.g. `{{patientForm.value.doctorId}}` or you can asign the value using setValue, e.g.  `<li (click)="patienForm.get('doctorId').setValue(d.id)">{{d.id}}</li>`.

Comment: @MikeOne yeah I thought about giving a click event but then I was confused about how to bind it with the doctorId, because even if i make a method then I have to call it inside ngOnInt and then have to set the doctorId formControll value explicitly which I don't know how to do

Comment: @Ani yeah that's why I am using bootstrap otherwise I would have gone with Select and option, but there has to be some way that I can use bootstrap DD with the reactive form this way

Comment: @Eliseo .setValue() is giving me unknown method

Comment: is `patientForm` (I forgot a "t")

Comment: no i corrected the typo I'm getting it after fixing the typo